# jsoncpp on vc90?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, scons, vc90, jsoncpp

anyone have [jsoncpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/) working on vc90?

they use a build system, Scons, which I have never heard of. I installed the latest Scons, found an undocumented scons.bat, launched a vc90 prompt in my jsoncpp dir, modified the SConstruct file to support a msvc90 target (i copied the boilerplate from the msvc80 platform which was already supported) ran `scons.bat platform=msvc90` and got errors:

```
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cl /Fobuildscons\msvc90\src\jsontestrunner\main.obj /c src\jsontestrunner\main.c
pp -GR -EHsc /nologo /MT /nologo /Iinclude /I.
main.cpp
c:\projects\docwayhead\wspt_docway_plugins\contrib\jsoncpp-src-0.5.0\include\jso
n\value.h(5) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'string': No such fi
le or directory
scons: *** [buildscons\msvc90\src\jsontestrunner\main.obj] Error 2
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

i've already put too much effort into getting this to build, and jsoncpp is clearly unmaintained, so i give up for now.

Answer (score 4):

No need to use Scons.

Under the */makefiles/vc71*/ you can find a visual studio solution which you can up convert and build.

Comment: It didn't Works for me I get an error message: 'unable to start program 'C:\myjsoncpp_location\Makefiles\vs71..../debug\lib_json\lib_json.ib'

Answer (score 0):

Modify the msvc90 platform file to make sure VC90 include directories are used when calling cl (clearly not yet the case in the provided command line you provided).

Note that Scons is written using Python and so are its configuration files, so people who know Python around you might be able to help you efficiently, even if they know nothing about scons.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your VS command line is working properly? I got it to work just by:
 - Adding a msvc90 entry in allowed_values
 - copy/pasting the msvc80 section later and modifying it to use env['MSVS_VERSION'] = 9.0

I'm using scons 1.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

The scons setup for jsoncpp 0.5.0 does not support VS 9.0 or 10.0 out of the box. You need to first add msvc90 to the allowed_values in the SConstruct line 21, and the to add this section on line 103.

```
elif platform == 'msvc90':
    env['MSVS_VERSION']='9.0'
    for tool in ['msvc', 'msvs', 'mslink', 'masm', 'mslib']:
        env.Tool( tool )
    env['CXXFLAGS']='-GR -EHsc /nologo /MT'
```

Just replace 9.0 with 10.0 and 90 with 100 for VS 10.0 support.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 0.6.0 of jsoncpp, you can avoid a lot of hassle by using the new Amalgamated version. This is just two .h files and one .cpp file that you compile directly into your projects. It's working great for me so far in VS 9 (and with a few mods I'm now able to compile it with C++Builder 2010 as well -- haven't really tested the result yet).

By the way, I've filed a bug against version 0.6.0-rc2; one line in the Amalgamated version of `json.h` needs to have a macro name changed.